# How to integrate Google map in BIRT report

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, birt

I want to show a Google map in my BIRT report.

Ideally this BIRT report should contain two sections. One table and Google map.

Table contains two filed longitude and latitude.

When clicking on a row I want to show corresponding location in Google map.

Can anyone post one sample design file which satisfying above requirement or share any link.

Comment: I downvoted your question, since SO is not the place where your work is done. To create links within a report see the BIRT documentation and if you want to integrate Maps see the Google Static Maps API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ Please also notice the usage limitations if you want to use this API in a commercial application.

Comment: @TomSeidel The question is not just about Google Maps API but its integration in BIRT. BIRT dont have good documentation to help so nothing wrong in posting it in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [rptdesign example](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/149-google-maps-mashup-with-birt-reports/) from birt-exchange

Comment: Answer is a broken link...  Don't make SO suck as bad as BIRT documentation / community please.